# Setting environment variables in eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables

I have a set of environment variables placed in a file, which I want to set when my project is launched via Eclipse.

I understand that we can set environment variables in run configuration, but there each variable has to be set manually. Is there a way through which I can set these variables from a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all file and folder paths inside the properties file (example config.properties) and then used it inside the testsetup method by

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("Path to//config.properties");
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.load(input);
                System.setProperty("log4j2.configurationFile", prop.getProperty("log4j.path"));
```

this way, all files/folder paths can be modifies from outside and there's no need to set environment variable from inside the project.