# Access property/environment variables without launching Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, log4j, environment-variables

I want to set the log4j configuration file path/other folder paths that can be used across other class files, without hard-coding the folder path.

Rightnow, I have set the variables as Environment variable. But It can only be modified if I launch Eclipse. How do I set this variable in such away that anyone (doesn't want to launch Eclipse) can modify it, from outside. Also, it will be used in test configurations. So it's better to not hard-code it and have all the file paths etc. easy to refactor.

```
final static String log4jpath = System.getenv("LOG4J_PATH");
```

Comment: It would help if you tell us if you're using some specific framework, there are lots of ways of doing what you want.

Comment: Selenium, TestNG and Log4j and I want to log lot of information but want to set the log4j config files and other test data files path ,"one place access everywhere" type of location. but don't want it hidden inside eclipse.

Comment: Which folder path, is it log4j configuration path or file path for log for logging ?

Comment: log4j configuration file path and driver paths, testdata file path etc.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you're simply asking how to [**set an environment variable**](https://www.google.com/search?q=set+an+environment+variable) from "outside" the Java program. If so, use `SET LOG4J_PATH=C:\path\to\whatever` (Windows) or `export LOG4J_PATH=/path/to/whatever` (Linux), before running Java program.

Comment: @Andreas , Yes outside of the Java program such as a separate file, that contains all other filepaths.  I saw someone asked same q's but there's no answer to it as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965751/setting-environment-variables-in-eclipse-project?rq=1

Comment: *"separate file, that contains **all other** filepaths"* That is called a **configuration file**, and is often a properties file, similar to the Log4j configuration file. To identify a single such file, you can use an environment variable (like you are right now), a system property (more common), or a specifically named file in the current directory, and then entries in that file will identify all the values you really want.

Comment: right, I just have found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paraphrasing a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367494/access-property-environment-variables-without-launching-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment99339203_56367494):

> [How to get value from] outside of the Java program such as a separate file, that contains all other filepaths?

That is called a **configuration file**.

It is often a properties file, similar to a Log4j configuration file, but it can be any types of file, e.g. XML, JSON, YAML, ...

To identify a single such file, you can use:

- An environment variable (like you are right now)
- A system property (more common)
- A specifically named file in the current directory
- ...

The entries in that file will identify all the values you really want.

For example, Spring, which is a populate Java framework, will look for configuration *values* in many places. See [24. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for full detail, but here is a summary of the most common ones:

- 4. Command line arguments, e.g. `java -jar MyApp.jar --foo=bar`
- 9. Java System properties, e.g. set using `-Dfoo=bar` on the command-line
- 10. OS environment variables, e.g. `SET foo=bar` (Windows) or `export foo=bar` (Linux)
- 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar, i.e. relative to current directory.
      Name and location can be overridden on command-line.

      - `config/application.properties`
      - `config/application.yaml`
      - `application.properties`
      - `application.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Soni, If you want to put the log4j configuration file in one place so that everybody can access. Follow the steps.

1. Create a project with some name and inside src/main/resources folder keep the log4j configuration file.
2. Create a jar file which must contain this log4j configuration file.
3. Use this created jar file wherever it is required. Log4j will automatically use the configuration for desired logging. If you want, you can distribute this jar file to anybody who wants to use it.

The above option is if you do not want to change the configuration file.

Now if there is a situation where someone wants to modify the configuration file.
In this case, simply put the configuration in any project classpath, means inside resource folder. As long as log4j jar files are there in the classpath and configuration files. It will log everything.

However, if you want, you can extend the functionality of Log4j by passing configuration as an object. You can refer below the link to access pro grammatically.

https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/how-to-programmatically-configure-appenders-in-log4j/

Comment: Is there an alternative way, of not hard-coding the paths? The solution you suggest is good if you don't want to change log4j config file forever. I was looking for String substitution in eclipse, but not sure how to use those variables inside the classes.

Comment: In this case there is no hard coding, it is part of that jar file.

Comment: But creating jar files is unnecessary step, if every time the configuration file changes

Comment: This is already case, what you've updated in your answer. log4j files everything is inside the project folder (inside eclipse), I want to avoid hard-coding the values for the remaining file paths and thisfile as well without setting the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have added all file and folder paths inside the properties file (example config.properties) and then used it inside the testsetup method by `InputStream input = new FileInputStream("Path to//config.properties");
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.load(input);
                System.setProperty("log4j2.configurationFile", prop.getProperty("log4j.path"));`

this way, all files/folder paths can be modifies from outside and there's no need to set environment variable from inside the project.